# Why is Lo-Dash _.each faster than Boiler.js _.each and Underscore.js _.each?

Tags: performance, javascript

[Perf Test](http://jsperf.com/underscore-each-vs-boiler-each/2)

Having not yet had the time to review the Lo-Dash code base (in great detail - work has me pretty strapped for time) I was wondering if someone could explain to me off the top of their head how Lo-Dash's `_.each` method out performs other libraries equivalents?

Comment: Now, looking at the code yourself should have been one of the first steps. You even might post them here so not everybody has to look them up.

Comment: What I meant was, i've not had the time to review the code base in any great detail. Work has me coding 14 hour days. I was hoping someone who just KNEW could answer instead of needing to do the research. :)

Answer (score 2):

Google is your friend, young grasshopper: http://kitcambridge.be/blog/say-hello-to-lo-dash/

In summary: Lo-Dash avoids using browser-native methods in favor of simple loops, which oddly enough are faster in most cases.