# Why is lodash.each faster than native forEach?

Tags: javascript, performance, lodash

I was trying to find the fastest way of running a for loop with its own scope. The three methods I compared were:

```
var a = "t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t,t".split();

// lodash .each -> 1,294,971 ops/sec
lodash.each(a, function(item) { cb(item); });

// native .forEach -> 398,167 ops/sec
a.forEach(function(item) { cb(item); });

// native for -> 1,140,382 ops/sec
var lambda = function(item) { cb(item); };
for (var ix = 0, len = a.length; ix < len; ix++) {
  lambda(a[ix]);
}
```

This is on Chrome 29 on OS X. You can run the tests yourself here:

http://jsben.ch/BQhED

How is lodash's `.each` almost twice as fast as native `.forEach`? And moreover, how is it faster than the plain `for`? Sorcery? Black magic?

Comment: I ran the test, and for me the native for loop was fastest (for: 1,771,709 vs forEach: 1,287,785 vs lo-dash: 236,743). In most cases, you won't even notice the difference, a few milliseconds here and there won't save you. Also, it would be quite hard to beat the native for loop, seeing as that is the only way to loop for an array (other than for..in, but that's not exactly proper).

Comment: See also [Why is Lo-Dash \_.each faster than Boiler.js \_.each and Underscore.js \_.each?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737711/why-is-lo-dash-each-faster-than-boiler-js-each-and-underscore-js-each)

Comment: What is that `lambda` thing for? Why don't you simply put `cb` directly?

Comment: In my actual code I'm creating some variables inside the for loop, so I need the contents to be scoped. My original code actually had `(function() { cb[ix] })();` inside the `for` loop, but I thought that wasn't a fair comparison since creating a new closure on each iteration is probably fairly expensive.

Comment: Lo-Dash's `.each()` is much slower than any other method in your test, for me. `FF 23.0.1`

Comment: The difference between `.each()` and `for` comes from the additional function lookup (`lambda`). See http://jsperf.com/lo-dash-each-vs-native-foreach/15 for a more meaningful benchmark.

Comment: native .forEach -> 398,167 ops/sec is plenty fast

Comment: I added 10000 elements to your test and the lodash each is now slower than the native foreach: http://jsben.ch/RBkjH

Answer (score 100, accepted):

`_.each()` is not fully compatible to `[].forEach()`. See the following example:

```
var a = ['a0'];
a[3] = 'a3';
_.each(a, console.log); // runs 4 times
a.forEach(console.log); // runs twice -- that's just how [].forEach() is specified
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BhrT3/

So lodash's implementation is missing an `if (... in ...)` check, which might explain the performance difference.

---

As noted in the comments above, the difference to native `for` is mainly caused by the additional function lookup in your test. Use this version to get more accurate results:

```
for (var ix = 0, len = a.length; ix < len; ix++) {
  cb(a[ix]);
}
```

http://jsperf.com/lo-dash-each-vs-native-foreach/15

Comment: Thanks for that. Worth pointing out though that the `for` without the closure is not entirely equivalent. The inside of the `for` block doesn't get its own scope.

Comment: @MattZukowski Your original [testcase](http://jsperf.com/lo-dash-each-vs-native-foreach/17) `for (...) {(function(item) {cb(item);})(a[ix]);}` is fine for that matter. Contrary to your comment above, this does not create considerable overhead for each iteration. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308446/how-big-are-javascript-function-objects

Comment: Lo-Dash gets its speed by treating all arrays as dense & hoisting out .call from the loop. Some JS engines may also have problems inlining across the native method boundary which lodash avoids by being plain JS. Treating all arrays as dense is more consistent cross-browser as IE < 9 will treat the literal `undefined` value in an array like `[null, undefined, false]` as a hole & skip it while others won't.

Comment: I get a 404 on that `jsperf` link.

Comment: I'm getting 404 as well. Did anyone see the results and which was faster?

Answer (score 27):

http://kitcambridge.be/blog/say-hello-to-lo-dash/

The lo-dash developers explain (here and on a video) that the relative speed of the native `forEach` varies among browsers.  Just because `forEach` is native does not mean that it is faster than a simple loop built with `for` or `while`.  For one thing, the `forEach` has to deal with more special cases.  Secondly, `forEach` uses callbacks, with the (potential) overhead of function invocation etc.

`chrome` in particular is known (at least to the lo-dash developers) to have a relatively slow  `forEach`.  So for that browser, lo-dash uses it's own simple `while` loop to gain speed.  Hence the speed advantage that you see (but others don't).

> By smartly opting into native methods — only using a native
> implementation  if it’s known to be fast in a given environment —
> Lo-Dash avoids the  performance cost and consistency issues associated
> with natives.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, lodash/underscore each don't even have same semantics as `.forEach`. There is a subtle detail that will make the function really slow unless the engine can check for sparse arrays without getters quickly.

This will be 99% spec compliant and [runs at the same speed as lodash each in V8](http://jsperf.com/lo-dash-each-vs-native-foreach/18) for the common case:

```
function FastAlmostSpecForEach( fn, ctx ) {
    "use strict";
    if( arguments.length > 1 ) return slowCaseForEach();
    if( typeof this !== "object" ) return slowCaseForEach();
    if( this === null ) throw new Error("this is null or not defined");
    if( typeof fn !== "function" ) throw new Error("is not a function");
    var len = this.length;
    if( ( len >>> 0 ) !== len ) return slowCaseForEach();


    for( var i = 0; i < len; ++i ) {
        var item = this[i];
        //Semantics are not exactly the same,
        //Fully spec compliant will not invoke getters
       //but this will.. however that is an insane edge case
        if( item === void 0 && !(i in this) ) {
            continue;
        }
        fn( item, i, this );
    }
}

Array.prototype.fastSpecForEach = FastAlmostSpecForEach;
```

By checking for undefined first, we don't punish normal arrays in the loop at all. An engine could use its internals to detect strange arrays but V8 doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an updated link (circa 2015) showing the performance difference which compares all three, `for(...)`, `Array.forEach` and `_.each`:
https://jsperf.com/native-vs-underscore-vs-lodash

*Note: Put here since I didn't have enough points yet to comment on the accepted answer.*

Comment: So it seems that `lodash.each` is no longer faster than `forEach` (Chrome 78, 2020)

Comment: Lodash is still faster on my machine (i9-9900k cpu @ 5Ghz 8core 16 thread) than native forEach, but a native for loop is double as fast as both of them (all of this according to running the test at that above URL).