# How to stop looping once it found?

Tags: javascript

If `three` is found then it should return true and stop the iteration. Otherwise return return false if not found.

I am using `filter()` - is it wrong approach to use?

```
var data = [
  'one',
  'two',
  'three',
  'four',
  'three',
  'five',
];

found = data.filter(function(x) {
   console.log(x);
   return x == "three";
});

console.log(found);
```

Demo: https://jsbin.com/dimolimayi/edit?js,console

Comment: `filter()` method, Runs the give function on **every item** in the array and returns an array of all items for which the function returns true;

Useful link : https://coderwall.com/p/_ggh2w/the-array-native-every-filter-map-some-foreach-methods

Comment: Nothing wrong with using `filter`, but you can use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to meet your requirements... Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23614054/javascript-nuances-of-myarray-foreach-vs-for-loop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) at this context,

```
var data = [
  'one',
  'two',
  'three',
  'four',
  'three',
  'five',
];

found = data.some(function(x) {
   return x == "three";
});

console.log(found); // true or false
```

If you use `filter`, then the array will be filtered based on the truthy value returned inside of the `callBack` function. So if any matches found meaning, if the function returned with value `true`, then the element on that particular iteration will be collected in an `array` and finally the array will be returned.

Hence in your case `["three", "theree"]` will be returned as a result. If you dont have any `"three"`, then an empty array would be returned, At this context you have to make a additional check to find the truthy value as a result.

For Example:

```
var res = arr.filter(itm => someCondition);
var res = !!res.length;
console.log(res); //true or false.
```

So to avoid that over killing situation we are using Array#some.

Comment: Thank you, to improve your answer - why my solution is wrong that I have used `filter`

Comment: You don't *"have to use"* .. it is merely one possible approach

Comment: Other alternative include [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)  & [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Thanks for great answer bro in great detail! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [
  'one',
  'two',
  'three',
  'four',
  'three',
  'five',
];

for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    console.log(data[i]);
  if(data[i]=="three"){
    var found=data[i];
    break;
  }
}

console.log(found);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return false to get out of function but you are already using return statement in filter function and you can not use 2 return statements ... One other solution i came up with is this :

```
var data = [
  'one',
  'two',
  'three',
  'four',
  'three',
  'five',
];

var filteredData = [];

function a(i,e){
   console.log(e);

  if(e == "three"){
    filteredData.push(e);
    return false;
  }
}

$(data).each(a);
console.log(filteredData);
```

This will break out as soon as it hits "three" and also stores it in filteredData array so you can use it in future ... 
Hope this helps ....

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward approach.

```js
    var data = [
      'one',
      'two',
      'three',
      'four',
      'three',
      'five',
    ];
    
    
    found = data.indexOf('three') == -1 ?  false :  true;
    console.log(found);
```

Comment: `indexOf` will also do looping under the hood and the passed value will be put under string checking `===`. You can see its algorithm in ecma's documentation.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, thanks for clarification. All loops under the hood, it seems. :)