# lodash : how to loop with between a start value and end value

Tags: javascript, loops, lodash

I've a for loop in javascript shown below. **How to** convert it to lodash for loop? 
In such scenarios using lodash is advantageous over javascript for loop?

I've not used lodash much. Hence please advice.

```
for (var start = b, i = 0; start < end; ++i, ++start) {
// code goes here
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to use lodash here?

Comment: Just trying out lodash. Want to explore it and how to use it in different scenarios,

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881487/why-is-lodash-each-faster-than-native-foreach

Comment: The only alternative I can think of is `each`ing a `range`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will imagine that `b = 3` and `end = 10` if I run your code and print the variables here is what I will get:

```
var b = 3;
var end = 10;

for (var start = b, i = 0; start < end; ++i, ++start) {
  console.log(start, i);
}

> 3 0
> 4 1
> 5 2
> 6 3
> 7 4
> 8 5
> 9 6
```

To perform this with lodash (or underscore) I will first generate an array with `range` then iterate over it and gets the index on each iteration.

Here is the result

```
var b = 3;
var end = 10;

// this will generate an array [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
var array = _.range(b, end); 

// now I iterate over it
_.each(array, function (value, key) {
  console.log(value, key);
});
```

And you will get the same result. The complexity is the same as the previous one (so no performance issue).

Comment: So, no performance or memory advantage, right? better to go with vanilla javascript for loop?

Comment: If you will use a lot of data manipulation lodash is always better than vanilla javascript.

see http://filimanjaro.com/blog/2014/introducing-lazy-evaluation/ for perfomance questions.

It is cleaner and more adaptive than vanilla js. If you only need a for loop it does not require a full library, but if you build a real application manipulating data, this lib is quite mandatory.

Answer (score 13):

You can use lodash `range`
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#range

```
_.range(5, 10).forEach((current, index, range) => {
    console.log(current, index, range)
})

// 5, 0, [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
// 6, 1, [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
// 7, 2, [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
// 8, 3, [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
// 9, 4, [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
// 10, 5, [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no lodash way for writing loose `for` loops (those not iterating over a collection), but here is a simplified version of it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < end - b; i++) {
      var start = i + b;
      // code goes here
}
```

Comment: OK. 
In that case, I will wait for some time until more suggestions come in and if  no more suggestions come in I will mark yours as solution.