# How to map the array values to dropdown's dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an nested array, and I have multiple dropdowns created using bootstrap.

I need to append all the **memQ** key values to dropdown1 and on change of that **memQ**, the corresponding **color** key values should populate.

I have filtered out the array and mapped the colors to corresponding **memQ**, but not able to map them to the dropdown's.

In the below attached Images, on select of each 128, 64, 16 etc.., corresponding colors should populate.

This is what I am expecting:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

This is what I tried:

HTML:

Dropdown 1:

```
<div class="col-sm-4" id="dropdown1">
    <ul class="sort-option">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="">Memory size</span>
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu col-sm-12">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"></a>
                    </li>

            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Dropdown 2:

```
<div class="col-sm-4" id="dropdown2">
    <ul class="sort-option">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="">Color</span>
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu col-sm-12">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"></a>
                    </li>

            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JSON:

```
var dSkuResp={"models":[{"deviceType":"Smartphone","name":"iPhone 6S","value":"iPhone 6S","variations":[{"memQ":"128","os":"iOS","color":"Gold","name":"Apple&reg; iPhone&reg; 6s 128GB in Gold","displayName":"iPhone 6S 128GB Gold","memU":"GB","maxValue":"335.0"},{"memQ":"128","os":"iOS","color":"Rose Gold","name":"Apple&reg; iPhone&reg; 6s 128GB in Rose Gold","displayName":"iPhone 6S 128GB Rose Gold","memU":"GB","maxValue":"335.0"},{"memQ":"128","os":"iOS","color":"Silver","name":"Apple&reg; iPhone&reg; 6s 128GB in Silver","displayName":"iPhone 6S 128GB Silver","memU":"GB","maxValue":"335.0"},{"memQ":"128","os":"iOS","color":"Gray","name":"Apple&reg; iPhone&reg; 6s 128GB in Space Gray","displayName":"iPhone 6S 128GB Space Gray","memU":"GB","maxValue":"335.0"},{"memQ":"16","os":"iOS","color":"Gold","name":"Apple&reg; iPhone&reg; 6s 16GB in Gold","displayName":"iPhone 6S 16GB Gold","memU":"GB","maxValue":"300.0"},{"memQ":"16","os":"iOS","color":"Rose Gold","name":"Apple&reg; iPhone&reg; 6s 16GB in Rose Gold","displayName":"iPhone 6S 16GB Rose Gold","memU":"GB","maxValue":"300.0"},{"memQ":"16","os":"iOS","color":"Silver","name":"Apple&reg; iPhone&reg; 6s 16GB in Silver","displayName":"iPhone 6S 16GB Silver","memU":"GB","maxValue":"300.0"},{"memQ":"16","os":"iOS","color":"Gray","name":"Apple&reg; iPhone&reg; 6s 16GB in Space Gray","displayName":"iPhone 6S 16GB Space Gray","maxValue":"300.0"},{"memQ":"64","os":"iOS","color":"Gold","name":"Apple&reg; iPhone&reg; 6s 64GB in Gold","displayName":"iPhone 6S 64GB Gold","memU":"GB","maxValue":"320.0"},{"memQ":"64","os":"iOS","color":"Rose Gold","name":"Apple&reg; iPhone&reg; 6s 64GB in Rose Gold","displayName":"iPhone 6S 64GB Rose Gold","memU":"GB","maxValue":"320.0"},{"memQ":"64","os":"iOS","color":"Silver","name":"Apple&reg; iPhone&reg; 6s 64GB in Silver","displayName":"iPhone 6S 64GB Silver","memU":"GB","maxValue":"320.0"},{"memQ":"64","os":"iOS","color":"Gray","name":"Apple&reg; iPhone&reg; 6s 64GB in Space Gray","displayName":"iPhone 6S 64GB Space Gray","memU":"GB","maxValue":"320.0"}]},{"deviceType":"Smartphone","name":"iPhone 6S","value":"iPhone 6S","variations":[{"memQ":"128","os":"iOS","color":"Blue","name":"Apple&reg; iPhone&reg; 6s 128GB in Gold","displayName":"iPhone 6S 128GB Gold","memU":"GB","maxValue":"335.0"},{"memQ":"128","os":"iOS","color":"Green","name":"Apple&reg; iPhone&reg; 6s 128GB in Rose Gold","displayName":"iPhone 6S 128GB Rose Gold","memU":"GB","maxValue":"335.0"},{"memQ":"128","os":"iOS","color":"Yellow","name":"Apple&reg; iPhone&reg; 6s 128GB in Silver","displayName":"iPhone 6S 128GB Silver","memU":"GB","maxValue":"335.0"},{"memQ":"128","os":"iOS","color":"Black","name":"Apple&reg; iPhone&reg; 6s 128GB in Space Gray","displayName":"iPhone 6S 128GB Space Gray","memU":"GB","maxValue":"335.0"},{"memQ":"16","os":"iOS","color":"Purple","name":"Apple&reg; iPhone&reg; 6s 16GB in Gold","displayName":"iPhone 6S 16GB Gold","memU":"GB","maxValue":"300.0"},{"memQ":"16","os":"iOS","color":"Maroon","name":"Apple&reg; iPhone&reg; 6s 16GB in Rose Gold","displayName":"iPhone 6S 16GB Rose Gold","memU":"GB","maxValue":"300.0"},{"memQ":"16","os":"iOS","color":"Pink","name":"Apple&reg; iPhone&reg; 6s 16GB in Silver","displayName":"iPhone 6S 16GB Silver","memU":"GB","maxValue":"300.0"},{"memQ":"16","os":"iOS","color":"Violet","name":"Apple&reg; iPhone&reg; 6s 16GB in Space Gray","displayName":"iPhone 6S 16GB Space Gray","maxValue":"300.0"},{"memQ":"64","os":"iOS","color":"Red","name":"Apple&reg; iPhone&reg; 6s 64GB in Gold","displayName":"iPhone 6S 64GB Gold","memU":"GB","maxValue":"320.0"},{"memQ":"64","os":"iOS","color":"Orange","name":"Apple&reg; iPhone&reg; 6s 64GB in Rose Gold","displayName":"iPhone 6S 64GB Rose Gold","memU":"GB","maxValue":"320.0"},{"memQ":"64","os":"iOS","color":"Carbon","name":"Apple&reg; iPhone&reg; 6s 64GB in Silver","displayName":"iPhone 6S 64GB Silver","memU":"GB","maxValue":"320.0"},{"memQ":"64","os":"iOS","color":"C Gray","name":"Apple&reg; iPhone&reg; 6s 64GB in Space Gray","displayName":"iPhone 6S 64GB Space Gray","memU":"GB","maxValue":"320.0"}]}]};
```

JS:

```
var colors = [];

_.each(dSkuResp.models, function(oVal, oIdx) {
    colors.push({});
    _.each(oVal.variations, function(nVal, nIdx) {
        if (!colors[colors.length - 1][nVal.memQ]) {
          colors[colors.length - 1][nVal.memQ] = [];
        }

        if (_.indexOf(colors[colors.length - 1][nVal.memQ], nVal.color) === -1) {
          colors[colors.length - 1][nVal.memQ].push(nVal.color);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Any demo? And sidenote: why don't you use `Array.forEach` instead of `_.each` ? #offtop lodash is just a silly wrapper around official array proto, although it may seem faster, just take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/18884620/2308005

Comment: I dint have any proper solution to create a demo, tht the reason i added the code what I tried along with the expected solution images

Comment: You should definitely make a simple [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demo, people don't like to parse bunch of words